# extracting text based on the sections in a pdf using python

Tags: parsing, pdf

I there a way to extract text from pdf based on the headings and sub headings. I'm able to extract text based on bookmarks using pdf plumber but there is  other use case where bookmarks are not there.

tried pdf plumber and pypdf2 libraries along with report lab

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can use pypdf to extracts text based on heading / subheadings here is an example

```
import PyPDF2

def extract_text_by_headings(pdf_path, heading):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
        text = ''
        for page_num in range(pdf.numPages):
            page = pdf.getPage(page_num)
            page_text = page.extractText()
            if heading in page_text:
                text += page_text
        return text

pdf_path = 'path/to/your/pdf.pdf'
heading = 'Heading 1'
extracted_text = extract_text_by_headings(pdf_path, heading)
print(extracted_text)
```